# Understaning 'Predicate must be expandable' error

Tags: expl3

I don't understand the commented version of this piece of code. `\regex_match:nnTF` is not expandable, so why should a predicate derived from it be defined as expandable?

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_const:Nn\__erw_this_regex{(?:foo)}
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn
%^^A\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn
\__erw_regex_match:n #1 {p}
%^^A\__erw_regex_match_protected:n #1 {p}
{\regex_match_p:Nn\__erw_this_regex{#1}}

% LaTeX3 Error: Predicate '\__erw_regex_match_protected_p:n' must be
%
%--- TeX said ---
%(LaTeX3)        expandable.

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

[doc](http://%60https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expl3's predicates are macros which expand to either `\c_true_bool` or `\c_false_bool`. Therefore these predicates must always be expandable, otherwise they can't operate as predicates.

Therefore `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \... {p}` is always an error since it would define a non-expandable predicate which can't exists.

For the same reason `\regex_match_p:Nn` isn't defined: It wouldn't be expandable, so it can't be a predicate.